# Gesturerecognizer on sub-view, getting error

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a subview (`UIImageView`) added to my main view. I want to detect taps in the subview only, and then run the 'processTap' method.

I get the following exception when it detects a click.

> "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView processTap]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Something seems to be wrong with the `@selector` portion.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  // Create a uiimage view, load image
  UIImageView *tapView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tap zone.png"]];
  tapView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 279, 298);
  tapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

  [self.view addSubview:tapView];

  // Initialize tap gesture recognizers
  UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:tapView 
                                     action:@selector(processTap)];
  singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

  [tapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)processTap {
    if (sessionRunning) {
        tapCounter = tapCounter + 1;
        _tapCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",tapCounter];
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The target for your recognizer has to be `self`.

```
// Initialize tap gesture recognizers
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(processTap)];
```

You have the previous error because your tapView hasn't a selector called `processTap`.

**NOTE**

From Apple's documentation:

> target
>
> An object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.

So, in this case the recipient for your action is the controller that implements `processTap` selector.